# Edit before DeepClone

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a really interesting question for you guys. I'm intending to clone product and the related lists, before saving the new record, I want to edit some of the fields. However, I run into the trap that:
1. I cannot load the records from related lists
2. I failed to save the records.

Visualforce

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="Product2" extensions="ControllerProductClone" action="{!doAction}" id="Page" showHeader="true">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.actionevent_js}" />
    <apex:form id="Form">
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!actionEvent}" id="actionEvent"/>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Product Info:"/>
        <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Product2">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doAction}" onclick="return setActionEventWithDiv{'Page:Form:actionEvent','Save'}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" action="{!Cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product Info" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Product Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <div class="requiredInput">
                            <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pageproduct.Name}"/>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Product Code</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <div class="requiredInput">
                            <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pageproduct.ProductCode}"/>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Redemption Qty</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <div class="requiredInput">
                            <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pageproduct.Redemption_Qty__c}"/>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Redemption Code</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!pageproduct.Redemption_Code__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Active</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!pageproduct.IsActive}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Etown Id</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!pageproduct.Etown_Id__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Description</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!pageproduct.Description}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product Item" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Item Type</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>




        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```java
public class ControllerProductClone extends BaseController{

    public Product2 pageproduct{get;set;}

    public ControllerProductClone(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        bindEventInterface();
        SetTransaction(false);
    }
    private void bindEventInterface(){
        controllerManager.bind('init', new ControllerProductCloneInit(this));
    }
    //Initialize the function
    private class ControllerProductCloneInit implements controllerManager.HandlerInterface{
        ControllerProductClone controller;
        public ControllerProductCloneInit(ControllerProductClone con){
            this.controller=con;
        }
        public PageReference handle(){
            return controller.Init();
        }
    }
    //Initialize the page
    private PageReference Init(){
        pageproduct = [select Id, Name, ProductCode, Etown_Id__c, Redemption_Code__c, Redemption_Qty__c,Description,IsActive
        from Product2 where Id =: CurrentRecordId limit 1];

        return null;
    }

    private PageReference CloneData(){
        String productquery =  getfieldSOQL('Product2', 'Id=\'' + CurrentRecordId + '\'');
        Product2 product = (Product2)Database.query(productquery);
        Product2 productnew = product.clone(false,true);
        Insert productnew;
        System.debug('New Product' + productnew.Id);

        String productitemquery = getfieldSOQL('ProductItem__c', 'Product__c=\'' + CurrentRecordId + '\'');
        List<ProductItem__c> itemdetails = Database.query(productitemquery);

        List<ProductItem__c> newitemdetails = itemdetails.deepClone(false);
        for(ProductItem__c t: newitemdetails){
            t.Product__c = productnew.Id;
        }
        if(newitemdetails.size()>0){
            Insert newitemdetails;
        }

        String productdiscountquery = getfieldSOQL('Product_Discount__c', 'Product__c=\'' + CurrentRecordId + '\'');
        List<Product_Discount__c> discoundetails = Database.query(productdiscountquery);

        List<Product_Discount__c> newdiscountdetails = discoundetails.deepClone(false);
        for(Product_Discount__c d: newdiscountdetails){
            d.Product__c = productnew.Id;
        }
        if(newdiscountdetails.size()>0){
            Insert newdiscountdetails;
        }

        String productpointrulequery = getfieldSOQL('AddPointRule__c', 'Product__c=\'' + CurrentRecordId + '\'');
        List<AddPointRule__c> pointdetails = Database.query(productpointrulequery);

        List<AddPointRule__c> newpointdetails = pointdetails.deepClone(false);
        for(AddPointRule__c r: newpointdetails){
            r.Product__c = productnew.Id;
        }
        if(newpointdetails.size()>0){
            Insert newpointdetails;
        }

        String productextraquery = getfieldSOQL('Product_Extra_Info__c', 'Product__c=\'' + CurrentRecordId + '\'');
        List<Product_Extra_Info__c> extradetails = Database.query(productextraquery);

        List<Product_Extra_Info__c> newextradetails = extradetails.deepClone(false);
        for(Product_Extra_Info__c e: newextradetails){
            e.Product__c = productnew.Id;
        }
        if(newextradetails.size()>0){
            Insert newextradetails;
        }

        return new PageReference('/' + productnew.Id);
    }


    public static String getfieldSOQL(String objectName, String whereClause){
        String selects = '';

        if(whereClause == null || whereClause == ''){return null;}

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fmap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName.toLowerCase()).getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
        List<String> selectfields = new List<String>();

        if(fmap != null){
            for(Schema.SObjectField ft: fmap.values()){
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = ft.getDescribe();
                if(dfr.isCreateable()){
                    selectfields.add(dfr.getname());
                }
            }
        }

        if(!selectfields.isEmpty()){
            for(String s:selectfields){
                selects += s + ',';
            }
            if(selects.endsWith(',')){
                selects = selects.substring(0, selects.lastIndexof(','));
            }
        }

        return 'SELECT ' + selects + ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE ' + whereClause;

    }

}
```

Comment: guys, the code is kind of long because of the repeated query and display. The scenario is: I'm writing the Apex and VF on product, and there are four custom objects look-up to the product. I wanna display the fields from custom object as well as editing them, afterwards, I should be able to save it with the rest is deepcloned.

Comment: Can you share the errors you get?

Comment: @Json Hi sir, the error is no error message actually, nothing happened when I click save button and there is nothing in the log.

Answer (score -1):

```
List < Module_Element__c > templateItemList = Database.query(fieldsToQuery);

            for (Module_Element__c items: templateItemList) {


                Module_Element__c clonedItem = items.clone(false, false, false, false);
                clonedItem .Module_Template__c = clonedmoduleTemplate.Id;
                newElementList.add(clonedItem);
            }

            if (newElementList.size() > 0) {

                Insert newElementList;
            }
```

Comment: Hi Gowtham, Thanks a lot for your reply! But I noticed that the only difference between you and me is that you use the clone(false, false, false, false) but I used deepclone in the iteration. But the problem is that I have to display the fields in VF and edit them. Thanks!

Comment: follw these steps. 1) Load the record values initially. set the new values for Fields.On submit button click call the clone method then clone the record with new values (Which is passed to the apex controller on submit click)